# How can I print something out during onCreate

Tags: android

During onCreate(), I'm downloading resources from the web, which takes time. I'd like to display a message on the screen to advise the user. I tried toast, but nothing shows up. Is there another way to print something to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

i think `onCreate()` work like a constructor for a class and you can not load any visual when it is not finished yet.
so i advice you to use another activity with your message and then call your activity in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a splash screen , that's the way it's called.
It's a mediator Activity that is handling such actions.

Example:

```
public class SplashScreen extends BaseActivity {
    public ProgressDialog ProgressBar = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        HideTitle();
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        if (!IsConnected()) {           
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    finish();
                }
            }, 4000);

        } else {
            ProgressBar = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", false, false);
            SplashScreenDelay splashScreenDelay = new SplashScreenDelay(this, this);
            splashScreenDelay.execute(10);
        }
    }
```

here is the class that does the loading and after that sends to the main

```
public class SplashScreenDelay extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, List<RssItem>> {
    private Context _context;
    private SplashScreen _activity;

    public SplashScreenDelay(SplashScreen activity, Context context) {
        _context = context;
        _activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        return RssParsingService.getListOfItems();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(_context, Viewport.class);
        _context.startActivity(intent);

        if (_activity.ProgressBar != null) {
            _activity.ProgressBar.dismiss();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the ProgressDialog just won't show up. What can possibly be wrong?